# How to boost MIT Scratch 3 performance in "full screen" mode?

Tags: html, performance, fullscreen, mit-scratch

I am using the version 3 of MIT-Scratch to create a simple game. It's running smooth in the [(smaller) editor view](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/287519910/editor/), but it hast quite significant lag (only a few fps) [in the full screen mode](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/287519910/fullscreen/), on the same machine. It's an older DELL machine.

**Why is there such a large difference between view modes and what can I do about it?**

Note: The game is very simple, just a backdrop and 2 animated sprites (no costume changes).

Note2: I tried both png and svg variants of the sprites and backdrop, but the performance does not significantly change, plus the difference is still clearly noticeable.

Note3: The overall performance differs a bit between browsers (Firefox / Chrome) and OS's (Windows 7 / Ubuntu), but the difference between edit/fullscreen is still significant.

Note4: On newer machines with more computing power (like my dev pc) this is not noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your computer's hardware, or the memory is being over-used. On my computer, there is no difference.

To try to circumvent this, try the following:

- Close all other tabs/windows
- Free up hard drive space

Answer (score 0):

Try https://turbowarp.org/. It compiles scratch as Javascript to make it run up to 10 times faster. Put in the project link and run. Note that it only works for shared projects.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30393558)